# Rabbitmq management plugins - RMQ 3.6.5

Tags: rabbitmq

I am having hard time here in enabling rmq management console on company laptop. I dont have admin rights to run cmd as admin here.

I am trying to enable console and see following output after that when I restart rabbit mq service and try to access console using http://localhost:15672, I am not able to access. I have also pasted output of list command for plugins.

(I am able to connect to broker via spring application though but cant access this console to view queues.)

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
The following plugins have been enabled:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  amqp_client
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_management

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@PCNAME... failed.
 * Could not contact node rabbit@PCNAME.
   Changes will take effect at broker restart.
 * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
            --offline - do not try to contact broker.





C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins list
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status:   [failed to contact rabbit@PCNAME - status not shown]
 |/
[e ] amqp_client                       3.6.5
[  ] cowboy                            1.0.3
[  ] cowlib                            1.0.1
[e ] mochiweb                          2.13.1
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.6.5
[E ] rabbitmq_management               3.6.5
[e ] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  1.2.1
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 0.1.0
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.6.5
[e ] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.6.5
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.6.5
[  ] sockjs                            0.3.4
[e ] webmachine                        1.10.3
```

Comment: "I am not able to access" is not helpful. The management plugin is enabled. What steps have you taken to check if port `15672` is open and has a listener? Hint: use `netstat`

Comment: netstat is not showing 15672. I have tried accessing via http://localhost:15672. Also I am confused with failed to contact rabbit@PCNAME status -  when trying to enable.

Comment: You probably are running into issues because you can't run a command window as an administrator. Also, check the RabbitMQ documentation for instructions on copying the Erlang cookie to your home directory. You don't say what version of Windows or Erlang you are using so I can't help further without that information.

Comment: I am on Windows 10. I can see cookie in c:/windows as well ass in c://users/myid -both has different values though.

Comment: its erlang 6.3.

Comment: Your Erlang version is too old, first of all. Second, read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html#erlang-cookie